# Вставить изображение с стороннего сайта

Tags: php, phpexcel

Пытаюсь вставить картинку со стороннего сайта.

```
$url_of_file = 'http://xxxxxx.ru/sgs/photo/199/999/199999_20150204085805.jpg';
$imag1=file_get_contents($url_of_file);
$imagePath = $imag1;

$sheet->getColumnDimension('G')->setWidth(40);

if (file_exists($imagePath)) {
    $logo = new PHPExcel_Worksheet_Drawing();
    $logo->setPath($imagePath);
    $logo->setCoordinates("G2");                
    $logo->setOffsetX(0);
    $logo->setOffsetY(0);   
    $sheet->getRowDimension(2)->setRowHeight(190);
    $logo->setWorksheet($sheet);
}
```

Сама картинка сохраняется через *file_put_contents()*.
Но когда я ее пытаюсь вставить в Excel не чего не вставляется.
Файл создает вписываются все прочие данные, и не выдает не каких ошибок.
Как можно загрузить картинку в Excel со стороннего сайта?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тут http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/discussions/271473 есть пример работы с картинкой:

```
$gdImage = imagecreatefromjpeg('images/officelogo.jpg');
// Add a drawing to the worksheetecho date('H:i:s') . " Add a drawing to the worksheet\n";
$objDrawing = new PHPExcel_Worksheet_MemoryDrawing();
$objDrawing->setName('Sample image');$objDrawing->setDescription('Sample image');
$objDrawing->setImageResource($gdImage);
$objDrawing->setRenderingFunction(PHPExcel_Worksheet_MemoryDrawing::RENDERING_JPEG);
$objDrawing->setMimeType(PHPExcel_Worksheet_MemoryDrawing::MIMETYPE_DEFAULT);
$objDrawing->setHeight(150);
$objDrawing->setWorksheet($objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet());
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');$objWriter->save(str_replace('.php', '.xlsx', __FILE__));
```

Тогда ваш код наверное (в правильности не уверен) будет выглядеть так:

```
$url_of_file = 'http://xxxxxx.ru/sgs/photo/199/999/199999_20150204085805.jpg';
$imag1=file_get_contents($url_of_file);

$sheet->getColumnDimension('G')->setWidth(40);

if ($imag1 !== false) {
    $logo = new PHPExcel_Worksheet_MemoryDrawing();
    $logo->setImageResource($imag1);
    $logo->setRenderingFunction(PHPExcel_Worksheet_MemoryDrawing::RENDERING_JPEG);
    $logo->setMimeType(PHPExcel_Worksheet_MemoryDrawing::MIMETYPE_DEFAULT);
    $logo->setCoordinates("G2");                
    $logo->setOffsetX(0);
    $logo->setOffsetY(0);   
    $sheet->getRowDimension(2)->setRowHeight(190);
    $logo->setWorksheet($sheet);
}
```

Comment: спасибо за наводку. вся соль была в функции `imagecreatefromjpeg`

Answer (score 0):

Потому что метод `setPath` видимо принимает путь к изображению. Попробуйте вместо `$imagePath` использовать `$url_of_file`.

Comment: а какая разница между $imagePath  и $url_of_file ?  этож вроде всего лишь имя переменной.   а вот что-то вместо setPath  будет в самый раз. только что???

Comment: потому что в $imagePath, результат выполнения file_get_contents($url_of_file), а эта функция уж точно возвращает не то, что Вам нужно

Comment: согласен.  file_get_contents тоже не то что нужно. ну что тогда в место нее ?

Comment: А почему бы не использовать URL к изображению?

Comment: прошу прощение. не совсем понимаю о чем вы. можете пример?

Comment: `$logo->setPath('https://www.google.com.ua/images/nav_logo225.png');`

Comment: пробовал не прокатывает ((